# Converting date from user input from 'mm/dd/yyyy' to 'Mm dd, yyyy'

Tags: python-3.x, list, slice

I want to convert the inputted date format and change the month from numbers to strings.

example user input (mm/dd/yyyy): **12/02/1999**

into: **Dec 02, 1999**

then this code

```
months = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'March', 'Apr', 'May', 'June', 'July',
          'Aug', 'Sept', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']

x = (input("Enter Date (mm/dd/yyyy): "))
spos = x.find('/')
print("Formatted Date (Mm dd, yyyy):", months[], x[spos+1:5], x[spos+4:])
```

where `months[]` will be where the corresponding date from the user input ***mm***/dd/yyyy

where ***Dec*** will taken from the list I made.

Comment: You can use `split()` to get the month, date and year

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `split()` to get month, date and year as string. Then you can just use the integer value of month to get the month string.

```
months = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'March', 'Apr', 'May', 'June', 'July',
          'Aug', 'Sept', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']

x = (input("Enter Date (mm/dd/yyyy): "))
mon, date, year = x.split('/')
month_str = months[int(mon) - 1]
print(f"Formatted Date (Mm dd, yyyy): {month_str} {date}, {year}")
```

You may want to add some error checking

In your approach, you can't use `months[]`. You have to use some index with that. You have already got the position of first `/` as `spos`. You can use that like -

```
print("Formatted Date (Mm dd, yyyy):", months[int(x[:spos]) - 1], x[spos+1:5], x[spos+4:])
```

Here `x[:spos]` will denote only the month value. After converting to integer using `int()` you can adjust the index to fetch appropriate month value.

But I think the above will be cleaner and easier to understand than this one.